# Find the value of the determinant.

Tags: determinant

[image: Here's what I did]

I know it equals 0 beause I solved it using minors, but I should solve it using determinants' properties. I have just detarted the determinant into 2, but I can't do nothing else.

Comment: Note that the sum of the second & third columns equals $a+b+c$ times the first column.

Comment: I don't know what you're using to make those images, but it might be easier to type it out in [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  For example, the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & b+c \\ 1 & b & c+a \\ 1 & c & a+b\end{vmatrix}$$ is obtained by typing `$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & b+c \\ 1 & b & c+a \\ 1 & c & a+b\end{vmatrix}$$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment by copper.hat, let's do the following

$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & b+c \\ 1 & b & c+a \\ 1 & c & a+b\end{vmatrix} &= \begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & b+c \\ 1 & b & c+a \\ 1 & c & a+b\end{vmatrix} + 0 \\ &= \begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & b+c \\ 1 & b & c+a \\ 1 & c & a+b\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a \\ 1 & b & b \\ 1 & c & c\end{vmatrix} \\ &= \begin{vmatrix}1 & a & a+b+c \\ 1 & b & a+b+c \\ 1 & c & a+b+c\end{vmatrix} \\ &= (a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix}1 & a & 1 \\ 1 & b & 1 \\ 1 & c & 1\end{vmatrix} \\ &= 0\end{align}$$

We took advantage of $2$ properties of determinants here:

1. The determinant of any matrix with a repeated row or column is $0$.
2. Determinants are [multilinear in their columns and rows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298536/what-operations-can-i-do-to-simplify-calculations-of-determinant/1298631#1298631).